# import {class} from 'path' returns undefined

Tags: javascript, class, import, export, undefined

I'm trying to import a Class from and external document into my web with the following code.

````
``` 
[File : root/js/circle.js]
// Circle object
export class Circle{
  constructor(position,size){
    this.position = position;
    this.size = size;
  }

  checkCollision(circle){
    return  this.position.distance2D(circle.position) <= (circle.size + this.size);
  }

  show(){
    ellipse(this.position.x, this.position.z);
    return;
  }

  lineTo(circle){
    line(this.position.x, this.position.z, circle.x, circle.z);
    return;
  }
}
console.log(Circle);
```
```
[File : root/js/main.js]
import {Circle} from './circle.js';
```
```
[File : root/index.html] 
<script type="module" src="js/main.js"></script>
```
````

My problem is that i can't access the "Circle" class from main.js, if i try to use "Circle" it returns "undefined", but i can see the "console.log" from circle.js.

Comment: Which build tools are you using? This looks like a circular dependency issue at first sight.

Comment: I don't have any dependency yet, i used my own set of functions for this, and there is none called "Circle" : https://i.gyazo.com/a36b6a488b2d2f07ab8d2273398f9f74.png
Also, im using XAMP for the server and the browser its Google Chrome.

Comment: when i run your code in main.js i can do `new Circle(0, 0)` and get a new instace of the Circle class.
what is your exact code that prints undefined?

Comment: " console.log(new Circle(0,0)) " https://i.gyazo.com/054fe508666aa91b61b53bd8e53997d9.png

I'm really confused now, i tried to coment everything else, and it still give me the same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import returns undefined instead of react component while testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46492902/import-returns-undefined-instead-of-react-component-while-testing)